# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on windows7: fsyncing/closing/dev/sda: input/output error. Partitions not detected and keyboard and mouse stop working

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have a Dell XPS 15z (l511z) latptop with windows 7 and I wish to install a dual-boot installation of ubuntu 14.04.2.
When booting from USB I get to the live installation and everything seems to work.
I quickly get an error in a pop-up window

```
Error fsyncing/closing/dev/sda: input/output error
```

When pressing retry the pop-up error persists, and when pressing ignore the installation can continue.
However, as soon as I push a button on my keyboard, both keyboard and mouse stop working.
I have tried plugging in both external USB mouse and keyboard but they stop working after a very short while also.

Sometimes the mouse works for so long that I can continue the installation prompts to the window where I select how and where I wish to install.
However, no partitions are detected on the drive.
The only option present is formating the entire drive and then installing linux on the empty drive, not what I wish to do.
When logged in to my windows I can confirm that I infact do have partitions on my drive.
I have a 1 TB harddrive where I have 35 GB unallocated where I wish to install Ubuntu.

When setting up my USB I have tried with both UnetBootin and Universal USB installer.
Naturally I have tried with another USB drive to make sure that the USB is not corrupt.
I have also tried installing Linux Mint with the exact same failure. Other information maybe worth mentioning is

- The file system is NTFS.
- In my BIOS setup, the only thing I can change that affects the harddrive (that I know of) is SATA Operations.
  Can be changed to ATA but at the moment it is selected to AHCI. I have no idea what this does...
- In Windows I have run CheckDisk to see if my harddrive is corrupt.
  This method did however not find any errors or faults.

Any help is greatly appreciated! At the moment I am only playing around with Xubuntu in VmWare...

Comment: Open a terminal and run `dmesg` for more detailed error messages.